# not able to perform drag and drop functionality in protratcor

Tags: protractor

i have tried these below ways to d drag and drop operation in protractor

1. browser.actions().
   mouseDown(element1).
   mouseMove(element2).
   mouseUp().
   perform();
2. browser.actions().
   dragAndDrop(element1, element2).
   perform();
3. browser.actions().
   mouseMove(element1).
   mouseMove({x: 50, y: 0}).
   doubleClick().
   perform();`

i have tried above all the three options , but drag and drop functionality did not work, only source element (in this case  element 1) was highlighted and it is displaying below error in console

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

The DOM code is below

```
<div class="catHoverDivClass ng-star-inserted" id="categoryNameVal" name="categoryNameVal" style="word-wrap: break-word;white-space: normal;width: 130px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;max-width: 100%;" ng-reflect-klass="catHoverDivClass" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
            Parent Category
        </div>

<div class="catHoverDivClass ng-star-inserted" id="categoryNameVal" name="categoryNameVal" style="word-wrap: break-word;white-space: normal;width: 130px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;max-width: 100%;" ng-reflect-klass="catHoverDivClass" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
            Category4
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
browser.driver.actions().mouseDown(element(sourceElement)).mouseMove(element(sourceElement)).mouseUp(destination).perform();
```

this is working for me.

Comment: above code is not working , it is displaying Failed: Invalid locator error message

Comment: i have updated the post with DOM Code , please refer that code

Comment: Cant you update the identifier and try?
Looks like you have tried with the same identifier as I used.